# Express Middleware, how do I skip last function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, middleware

I am using express in Node.js and I use a function inside a get route...
The function first has an own-coded simple caching functionality implemented, and then it queries some data from a MSSQL Database and returns it in res.json(data). But I would like to refactor my cashing function, and put it inside an own function and call it as express middleware. But somehow, I tried out a lot but don't really know how to do it. Below is my refactored function checkTime().

```
router.get("/v1/watch/readindex", async function(req,res) {
 ///////////////////////////CASHING///////////////////////////////////
    var timediff = config.get('write.cachetime'); //get cachetime - same for write or read
    timediff = 30000; //testing
    var timenow = Date.now();         
    if (!cachedtimeread || !readmsg || (cachedtimeread < (timenow-timediff))) {
        readmsg = "";
        cachedtimeread = timenow;  
        readtimemsg = `Zeit vergangen seit letztem Aufruf:  ${msToTime(cachedtimeread -timenow)}. API wurde aufgerufen.\n<br>`;
    }       
    else if (cachedtimeread >= (timenow - timediff)) { //API-Aufruf jünger als Aufrufzeitpunkt - timediff
        readmsg += `Zeit vergangen seit letztem Aufruf:  ${msToTime(cachedtimeread -timenow)}. Dokument ist aus dem Cache!\n<br>`; 
        //console.log("Funktion für Dokument-Query wurde nicht aufgerufen!");
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.json(readmsg);
        return;
    } 
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    axios.all([read = await count_ES_read(), await mssqlQuery(mssqlQueryLessOneDay), 
        await mssqlQuery(mssqlQueryLessEightHours), await mssqlQuery(mssqlQueryTotal) ])
    .then(axios.spread(function (resultES_read, mssqlLessOneDay, mssqlLessEightHours, mssqlTotal) {  
        readmsg=''; 
        var elasticsearchcount = resultES_read.count;

        var mssqlLessOneDay = mssqlLessOneDay.recordset[0].count;
        var mssqlLessEightHours = mssqlLessEightHours.recordset[0].count;
        var mssqlTotal = mssqlTotal.recordset[0].count;

        //console.log(elasticsearchcount, mssqlLessOneDay, mssqlLessEightHours, mssqlTotal);
        readmsg += `Umgebung: ${process.env.NODE_ENV} READ<br>`;
        readmsg += `ES Dokumente insg:  ${elasticsearchcount}  MSSQL Dokumente insg:  ${mssqlTotal} <br>`;
        if ( elasticsearchcount < mssqlLessOneDay) {
            readmsg += `Critical:   ${mssqlLessOneDay - elasticsearchcount} , weniger Dokumente in ES als im Dokumente-Pool die älter als 1 Tag sind. <br>`; 
        } if ((elasticsearchcount < mssqlLessEightHours))  {            
            readmsg += `Warning: ${mssqlLessEightHours - elasticsearchcount} , weniger Dokumente in ES als im Dokumente-Pool, die älter als 8 Stunden sind. <br>`;
        } if ((elasticsearchcount > mssqlTotal))  {  
            readmsg += `Achtung: ES-Dokumente Anzahl > Dokumente im Dokumente-Pool. Es gibt ${elasticsearchcount - mssqlTotal} ungelöschte Dokumente im Elasticsearch Index!`;
        }                          
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.json(readmsg);
        })).catch((err) => {
            res.send(err);
        });
});
```

This function should retrieve the output for the message from the database query from the last async-function above, in case the timestamp from the last api-route call is still younger than some timestamp in milliseconds. If thats not the case, the last function call to retrieve the data should be executed. 
But I don't know how to retrieve the message variable from the async function, saving it in `res.locals` somehow didnt work, and furthermore, I don't know how to skip the last function call then. Somehow, the return after the res.json() in the middleware does not work and the async-function is always executed, but I want to quit the checkTime() function and return the message in res.json if the document is younger than `now-timestamp`.

```
function checkTime(writemsg) {
        return function(req,res,next) {
        var timediff = config.get('write.cachetime'); //get cachetime - same for write or read
        timediff = 30000; //testing
        var timenow = Date.now();         
        if (!cachedtimewrite || !writemsg || (cachedtimewrite < (timenow-timediff))) {
            writemsg = "";
            cachedtimewrite = timenow;  
            writetimemsg = `Zeit vergangen seit letztem Aufruf:  ${msToTime(cachedtimewrite -timenow)}. API wurde aufgerufen.\n<br>`;
            next();
        }       
        else if (cachedtimewrite >= (timenow - timediff)) { //API-Aufruf jünger als Aufrufzeitpunkt - timediff
            writemsg += `Zeit vergangen seit letztem Aufruf:  ${msToTime(cachedtimewrite -timenow)}. Dokument ist aus dem Cache!\n<br>`; 
            //console.log("Funktion für Dokument-Query wurde nicht aufgerufen!");
            res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.json( writemsg);
            return;
        } 
    }
}


router.get("/v1/watch/writeindex", checkTime(writemsg), async function(req,res,next) {
```

//////////////EDIT:

One of the functions which I use in Promise.all() to get the data from db is this:

```
var mssqlQuery = (query) => {  
    if (!query || query =="") {
        throw new Error('Query for MSSQL was not defined!');        
    }
    //console.log("Query: ", query);
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(mssqlconfig);
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);
    return  conn.connect().then(async() => {       
            var result = await req.query(query);
            //conn.close();
            return result;            
            //conn.close();
           }).catch(e => {
                return e;
           }).finally(() => {
                conn.close();
           });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or I have a problem understanding your question, or you do not quite understand how express middlewares works.

```
function checkTime(writemsg) {
  return function(req,res,next) {
    if(foo) {
      req.storeValueKey = 'data to store'
      next(); // run next middleware
    } else {
      res.json('stop processing');
    }
  }
}
router.get('/url',checkTime('message'), (req, res) => {
  console.log('data form middleware', req.storeValueKey)
  res.json('send data collected from DB' + req.storeValueKey);
  req.session.storeValueForNextRequests = 'val';
})
```

*//EDIT BEGIN*

In middleware you can use `next()` or `res.send()`. It is a mistake to use both. And you must remember that the use of `next()` and `res.send()` does not interrupt the execution of the parent function. (remember  about `return`)

```
res.send('Text response');
next();
thisIsAlsoRun();
```

And you know, in your middleware is "black hole". If both `if` are `false` you stuck in middleware, so add `else next()` to avoid this

*//EDIT END*

Additionally, I am bothered with the question: Why do you use an HTTP client to collect data from promises and why are you using await there?

Node should do it one by one, not asynchronously. (Unless it's smarter and ignore this wrong syntax).

At the beginning, stop using `await` in `Promise.all`.

Then use the [native `Promises` instead of those from the axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042#issuecomment-331470391) http client.

```
Promise.all([count_ES_read(),mssqlQuery(mssqlQueryLessOneDay), 
        mssqlQuery(mssqlQueryLessEightHours), mssqlQuery(mssqlQueryTotal) ])
    .then(function (resultES_read, mssqlLessOneDay, mssqlLessEightHours, mssqlTotal) {
        req.storeValueKey ; 
    })
```

//Edit 2

I see that you have huge problems understanding  `async/await` and `Promisses`. Node is based on events (eg getting results)

Very generalizing `await` means: "*Wait until you continue to perform the function until you get the results.*" And `Promisses`: "*create a pipe that will handle`then` and process the instructions further*."

The sense of using `Promise.all()` is when you put Promisess there. But you're shaping the execution using `await`

```
const mssqlQuery = (query) => {  
    if (!query || query =="") {
        throw new Error('Query for MSSQL was not defined!');        
    }
    //I will not investigate whether you are doing well making a call with each request.
    const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(mssqlconfig);
    const req = new sql.Request(conn);
    return  conn.connect().then(() => {
            // Promise can return promise
            let result = req.query(query);
            conn.close();
            return result;            
        });   
}
const mssqlNoErrorQuery = (query) => {
    return mssqlQuery(query).catch( e => { 
        return null; // no results 
        // OR fake resultset count
        return {recordset:[{count:null}]};
        /*
        return e; // this will cause the error in the next stage 
        //to be treated as a correct situation.
        // Next you should take care of it in such a way:
        let res = await mssqlQuery(query);
        if(res instanceof Error)
            console.error('something wrong')
        else    
            res.recordset[0].count
        */
    });
}

let [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
    mssqlNoErrorQuery(query1),
    mssqlQuery(query2).catch(e =>{/* local error handling */})
])
```

To better understand the whole idea, you should do some experiments with this code:

```
function sleep(ms){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        setTimeout(resolve,ms)
    })
}

function wait(msg) {
    return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
        console.log('START '+ msg)
        await sleep(700)
        console.log('finish '+ msg)
        resolve(true)
    } )
}

let fo = async () => {
    Promise.all([await wait('d'), await wait('e'), await wait('f')]).then((c,d,e)=> {console.log('collect CDE')})

    Promise.all([wait('a'),wait('b'),wait('c')]).then((c,d,e)=> {console.log('collect ABC')})
}

fo();
```

result:

```
START d  12:22:06 PM
finish d 12:22:07 PM
START e  12:22:07 PM
finish e 12:22:07 PM
START f  12:22:08 PM
finish f 12:22:08 PM
START a  12:22:08 PM
START b  12:22:08 PM
START c  12:22:08 PM
collect CDE
finish a  12:22:09 PM
finish b  12:22:09 PM
finish c  12:22:09 PM
collect ABC
```

BTW: did you notice that the process a, b, c started before collecting results from c, d, e?

Now change to:

```
let fo = async () => {
    Promise.all([wait('a'),wait('b'),wait('c')]).then((c,d,e)=> {console.log('collect ABC')})
    Promise.all([await wait('d'), await wait('e'), await wait('f')]).then((c,d,e)=> {console.log('collect CDE')})
}
```

Result:

```
START a
START b
START c
START d
finish a
finish b
finish c
finish d
collect ABC
START e
finish e
START f
finish f
collect CDE
```

As you see here starts all promises from 1 call and fitst from second call

Comment: you understood almost everything, except that I have another res.json in my last function call, and depending on the condition from the middleware function, I either want to return  my res.json response in the middleware, and then not execute the res.json in my last function, or I want to skip the middleware, and do a res.json in the last function...If I am doing both, I get a "can't set headers after they are sent.."

Comment: furthermore, I am doing database queries inside axios.all([...]), so why shouldn't I do it?

Comment: You should not to do this because it is a bad practice. Not executing queries in `all()`, but use `axios`. Couple years ago *promisses* were not available naively in Node and then it was OK. But now they are, so please use native syntax. (And there are plans to remove this helpers in axios 1.0, see lnk) + see updates answer

Comment: I edited one of the functions to retrieve the data in my post. Why should I fetch the data from db sequentially instead of in parallel? My db request takes about 1 minute and I have to do 4 of them, so it takes a lot of time if I don't do it in parallel. And why can't I do the requests in Promise.all()? And why not use "await function()" to wait for the results in axios, is there another way to do it? I didn't know how..

Comment: You fetch data sequentially when you use `await`. Check answer.

Comment: ok thanks I didn't know that, so I replaced the await function() with just the function handler inside Promise.all() function, that should do it in parallel, right? Or is there another way to do asynchronous calls simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. BTW: remember `.then(()=> {reurn await})` can be replaced by `then().then()` Promise can return next promise, not only "flat" result